# React Native Remote Debugger shows cached bundles in Chrome

Tags: react-native

When I'm trying to use Remote JS Debugging in Google Chrome shows Cached Bundles. See the image below.

Remote Debugger UI Screenshot:
[image: Remote Debugger UI Screenshot]

On my emulator its not connecting to remote debugger.
Android Emulator Screenshot
[image: Android Emulator Screenshot]

Is there anyone who encountered this problem?

I'm using React Native Version 0.47.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you use Chrome, clear cache from browser and reload app from react native. This fix my issue :)

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me!

Comment: Thank you very much, the answer save me a day !

Comment: Good @IvanKramarchuk

Answer (score 11):

Get rid of that final forward slash and it should kick you to the normal debug window. I'm running 64.0.3282.186 version of Chrome and this works for me. However, I know someone who says they get force redirected to the address with the forward slash, so I hope you're not in that boat.

Comment: The cause of his issue was that Chrome was trying to forward to that address with the slash. Nuking his cache, history, etc got things working properly again. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @mcdone. It's working now. What I did is to clear the cached image and files on my google chrome. And it's working again. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you. This allowed me to run the debugger in opera in mac (trying to move away from memory eater called chrome :D )

Answer (score 3):

To fix the error, you need to clear your cache in chrome and it will work again.

Answer (score 0):

Close the packager and install the app again. This worked for me.